# IIS ARR Rule. Match all but

Tags: iis, rules, arr

I got the Virtual Host in my IIS:

```
http://sampleserver.org
```

I want to redirect this URL to a tomcat application `http://localhost:8081/one`

But I **don´t** want to redirect the url

`http://sampleserver.org/two` to `http://localhost:8081/one/two`

So my rule looks like this:

```
<rule name="Root zu Client" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="false">
  <match url=".*" ignoreCase="false" negate="false" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^two" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8081/one/{R:0}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

I want to redirect everything but `^two` to the tomcat.

Is this not possible or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Pattern is not correct. If you don't want redirect url like http://sampleserver.org/two you must apply this:

```
  <rule name="RuleTWO" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="*" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="*/two*" negate="true"/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8081/one/{C:2}" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: This: [Emptyness] ? Or do you mean an ending Slash?